# how to set default item in Select2 on Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4, ui-select2

how to set default item in Select2 on Yii2

> The initSelection method of Select2 3.5.x plugin is obsolete/removed.
>   New initValueText property is been provided with the Select2 widget to
>   cater to this (e.g. for ajax based loading).

but initValueText dont work!!!

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php
            $categories = [5 => 'test1', 7=> 'test2', 8=> 'test3'];
            echo Select2::widget([
                'initValueText' => $categories,
                'model' => $modelKani,
                'name' => 'Kani',
                'id' => 'Kani',
                'data' => $data,
                'showToggleAll' => false,
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Insert Item',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'minimumInputLength' => 2,
                    'dir' => 'rtl'
                ],
            ]);
            ?>
    </div>
```

result $data:

```
Array
(
    [5] = test1
    [7] = test2
    [8] = test3
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

work with this:

```
'value' => [5, 10]
```

item id 5,10 from $data

Doc:

> http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-tags

Answer (score 1):

Provide `model` and `attribute` OR `name` and `value`. You have provided `model` and `name` so `model` is ignored and `value` is set to `null`.

As for the `initValueText` - its description states: "the displayed text in the dropdown for the initial value when you **do not set or provide `data`** (e.g. using with ajax)". You have provided `data`.